# How nginx manages to show its landing page even when the landing page index.html file and the rule in config is deleted

Tags: nginx

I've deleted the nginx landing page index file from `/var/www/html`. My nginx config (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`) is

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
}
```

How does nginx manage to return its landing page when I hit localhost, even when there's nowhere it's mentioned? I've even deleted the index file from `/var/www/html` where the landing page resides, nginx manages to show its landing page.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser's cache?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, cleared browser cache, tried private window and different browser.